# I am stuck trying to create a script for reading a txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script for reading a txt file and calculating data

The purpose of creating this is to read a txt file with data such as

```
John Smith  11/18/2022 9:33 7.96
Chris Rock  11/19/2022 9:31 8.64
Jane Doe    11/12/2022 10:08 7.6
John Smith  11/9/2022 12:18 5.28
```

I am curious how I can create objects with each name and check if a object has been created with the name, if so update a total hours variable of the object.

for ex creating a object called JohnSmith and update the hours to 7.96
the program goes the the next line and creates a object called ChrisRock and updates this hours to 8.64. When the program reaches the second JohnSmith it will not create a new object but instead update the original JohnSmith objects hours from 7.96 to  13.24 (7.96+5.28)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a new user, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask].
It might also help to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to create a dictionary with names as keys, and hours as values.

You could do something like:

```py
hours_dict = {}


with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # parse the line to extract the name and hours
        name = ...
        hours = ...

        if hours_dict.get(name):
            hours_dict[name] += hours
        else:
            hours_dict[name] = hours
```

Comment: hours_dict[name] will generate an error if 'name'  is not in the dictionary. Instead, you should use "if hours_dict.get( name):". The solution has not been tested.

Comment: @user3435121 Sorry about that. Were you unable to make an edit to fix that?